# Hide Zapier Webhook URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, webhooks, zapier

I am new-ish to web development, and I have a site that is using a Zapier webhook to pass info. Since this is a custom site, I am directly posting to Zapier's URL to pass parameters.

My concern is that this URL is unprotected and can be found by simply inspecting the page. How can I go about better protecting it so that it's not visible to others?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var webhookURL = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/XXXX/XXXX/";
var data = {
   "First Name" : userName.value,
   "Email" : userEmail.value,
};
request.open("POST", webhookURL, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(JSON.stringify( data ));
```

Comment: Only by using a proxy server, that you send your request from the client side to, and that will then pass it on to the webhook. But then the proxy URL will be visible to everyone, and they could send their own request there instead ... So if you want to protect the whole thing against "abuse", you will probably have to introduce some sort of authentication, on some levrl.

Comment: @CBroe Do you think the protection is that necessary? For what it's worth, this isn't going to be some mega travelled site, but I, of course, want to protect it if I need to.

Comment: That really rather depends on what you actually want to achieve by this.

Comment: @CBroe So this is a calculator site where users have to provide their email and name to see results, which directs them into a sales funnel (all opt-in of course). Sending over their email and name is where the URL for the webhook is. So if someone were to spam it for some reason, they would give us a bunch of fake email addresses but not really break anything. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, a proxy without any further authentication or access control would still have the same problem, unless you had a way to somehow "validate" requests on the proxy side.

Comment: @CBroe Ok I guess I'll just have to live with it unless there's some other magical solution. Thanks for the advice!